# Improve JOLT spec to get expected result

Tags: json, jolt

Source JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "other": false,
    "granularity": [
      {
        "impressions": 15,
        "date": "2021-11-02"
      },
      {
        "impressions": 67,
        "date": "2021-11-03"
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "adGroupId": 5792423,
      "startTime": "2021-06-29T21:00:00.000"
    }
  },
  {
    "other": false,
    "granularity": [
      {
        "impressions": 226,
        "date": "2021-11-02"
      },
      {
        "impressions": 2339,
        "date": "2021-11-03"
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "adGroupId": 578101600,
      "startTime": "2021-06-29T08:05:52.176"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried with this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "granularity": {
          "*": "[&2].&"
        },
        "metadata": {
          "adGroupId": "[&2].adGroupId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "0": {
      "impressions": 15,
      "date": "2021-11-02"
    },
    "1": {
      "impressions": 67,
      "date": "2021-11-03"
    },
    "adGroupId": 5792423
  },
  {
    "0": {
      "impressions": 226,
      "date": "2021-11-02"
    },
    "1": {
      "impressions": 2339,
      "date": "2021-11-03"
    },
    "adGroupId": 578101600
  }
]
```

I want to remove these indexes `0,1,...etc` from top level. And `adGroupId` should be in each row.

So I expect this result:

```json
[
  {
    "impressions": 15,
    "date": "2021-11-02",
    "adGroupId": 5792423
  },
  {
    "impressions": 67,
    "date": "2021-11-03",
    "adGroupId": 5792423
  },
  {
    "impressions": 226,
    "date": "2021-11-02",
    "adGroupId": 578101600
  },
  {
    "impressions": 2339,
    "date": "2021-11-03",
    "adGroupId": 578101600
  }
]
```

How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the key-value pairs under the `granularity` key while prefixing the subkeys by `[&3].&1.` in order to pick the common indexes by going three levels up, and then remove the keys of the indexes at the last step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "granularity": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&3].&1.&",
            "@(2,metadata.adGroupId)": "[&3].&1.adGroupId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]